# Receiving output from Power shell script in C# and using it to further guide my C# code

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to make a Windows Form application in C# to run Power-Shell commands that will make changes to Active Directory Computer objects.

I have gotten the part of the code that makes the change to work but i need a section to check the Current Description property and return that to do a if statement on it. I am trying to figure out how to get the output from my first Power-Shell command to go to a string value so i can continue in C# the Power-Shell Script was created by a Co-Worker and am looking to try and improve on it.

I have tried using methods from other helps [Output Result from Powershell command to C# variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365824/output-result-from-powershell-command-to-c-sharp-variable)

And I either get just the computer name or the computer name and ``` System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection``1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject] ```

```
private void ChangeDefault_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    oldistag = OldISTag.Text;
    newistag = NewISTag.Text;
    computeristags = ComputerIstag.Text.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    computeristagsout = new string[computeristags.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < computeristags.Length; i++)
    {
        // PS script "Get-ADComputer -Identity " + "ISC110476" + " -Properties Description | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description"
        // returns  a single line in powershell ISC108956
        var script = "Get-ADComputer -Identity " + computeristags[i] + " -Properties Description | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description";

        PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(script);           


        var current = powerShell.Invoke();

        computeristagsout[i] = computeristags[i] + currentdesc + current;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Scripts\output.txt", computeristagsout[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < computeristagsout.Length; i++)
    {
        output.Text += computeristagsout[i] + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

What I expect to get would be just the results in the Description field if there is anything there.

I have been getting ``` System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection``1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject] ```

Comment: Cast the `PSObject` to string: `(string)current[0]`

Comment: Show or log the variable `script` before you execute it in powershell and see if it gives you the required result when you execute it manually in powershell console. I think you're missing a whitespace before `-Properties`

Comment: @Fourat thank you for pointing out the missing whitespace i did correct that in the code but still get the same issue. When running the command straight in Powershell i do get the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```cs
using System.Linq;
// ...
var script = "$(Get-ADComputer -Identity " + computeristags[i] + " -Properties Description | Select -ExpandProperty Description)";
PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(script);           
var collection = powerShell.Invoke();
var current = collection.First();
computeristagsout[i] = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", computeristags[i], currentdesc, current);
```

The cmdlet `Select-Object` returns an object that's why you're getting the output of `System.Management.Automation.PSObject::ToString`. You need to use `Select` which returns text combined with `-ExpandProperty` (giving it **only one** argument) then you'll get a `string` that you can use in your logs.

Comment: i made the change that you sugested and i am still getting the following as the output 
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]

Comment: I was able to make the changes above except for the string.format as it was giving me a error saying "String does not contain a definition for format" i was able to use my original line of code for that one and it worked thank you for the help.

Comment: @CharlesShepherd I fixed it it's `string.Format`