# Executing Powershell script in c# and wait for the result

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, object, console-application

I have a console application and a method that executes a PowerShell script within the console application. So what I'm trying to achieve is running it and then waiting for the result before reading the next method. How would I go about this?

This already outputs the result. I just want to wait for the result to finish rather than jumping to the next method prematurely.

Example/what I'm trying to do

```
     Process.Start()
        //Wait for result here
```

The current method is below:

```
public void ExecutePowershellScript()
{
  var file = @"C:\Path\filename.ps1";
           
            var start = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{file}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            Process.Start(start);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output Result from Powershell command to C# variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365824/output-result-from-powershell-command-to-c-sharp-variable)

Comment: No. This already outputs the result. I just want to wait for the result to finish rather than jumping to the next method prematurely. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure I understand your question. Are you looking for a way to wait until process finishes before continue the program execution ? if yes, there is an easy way:

```
process.WaitForExit()
```

[Check out documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=net-5.0#:%7E:text=WaitForExit%20%28%29%20makes%20the%20current%20thread%20wait%20until,for%20the%20process%20and%20event%20handlers%20to%20exit.). Execute PowerShell script is actually start a new process. So, to guarantee that the execution has finished is simply waiting for process to exit.