# Calling query results from Powershell into C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am new to Powershell.

I am trying to insert the query results of [this Powershell code](https://github.com/craibuc/PsIntacctSdk/blob/master/PsIntacctSdk/Public/Find-IntacctSdkObject.ps1) into C# variable called "results".

I got the C# sample code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365824/output-result-from-powershell-command-to-c-sharp-variable) to get the result of Powershell into C#.

```
var results = ps.Invoke();
foreach (var psobject in results)
{
  var myInteger = Convert.ToInt32(psobject.Members["SomeField"].Value);
}
```

By looking at [this Powershell code](https://github.com/craibuc/PsIntacctSdk/blob/master/PsIntacctSdk/Public/Find-IntacctSdkObject.ps1), on line 39 and 40,

```
# results of query
[Intacct.SDK.Xml.OnlineResponse]$Response = $task.Result
```

the object name for the query results seems to be [Intacct.SDK.Xml.OnlineResponse]$Response.
Is it?

**1) What would be expression to get the result of this Powershell and put inside C#?**

**2) Do I have to install PowerShell Tool into Visual Studio to see the "PowerShell" object to be recognized** (shows up without an error)?

And, why is this extension trial version?

[image]

[image]

I am trying to understand how powershell code works within C# solution.

**3) Do I just create ps1 code like this and add to the solution?**
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: "*And, why is this extension trial version?*" - because you haven't bought it? https://ironmansoftware.com/pricing/powershell-pro-tools

Comment: It's a Powershell wrapper for .Net, so why not use the library right from C#?

Comment: @vonPryz Sorry. how do I use the library from C#? Can you please elaborate? So new to this. Thanks.